# How to identify each IceFaces inputFile tag that are created using panelSeries to pass to backing bean?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm using Eclipse Stardust 4.1, JSF 1.2, IceFaces 3.3. In this script, it will create multiple input file tags, but I want to be able to identify the file being uploaded to have come from which input file tag based on `#{docObject.type}`. How do I pass this information to the backing bean `#{DocObject.uploadFiles}`? Thank you.

```
<ice:panelSeries var="docObject" value="#{IndividualRegistrationBean.docList}">
    <ice:panelGrid columns="1" style="border:1px dotted silver;" width="100px">
        <ice:outputText value="#{docObject.type} - #{docObject.description}" /> 
        <ice:inputFile id="doc" title="#{docObject.type}" width="600" autoUpload="true"
                        actionListener="#{DocObject.uploadFiles}" />
    </ice:panelGrid>
</ice:panelSeries>
```